# How to change onClick event with onMouseEnter/onMouseOut ? Tailwind-UI component

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I have this store navigation tailwind-UI component : *https://tailwindui.com/components/ecommerce/components/store-navigation*

I want that menu categories (Women/Men) to open when I hover over, and close when hover out; not open/close on click. How can I do that ?
**Please help!!**

Answer (score 0):

You can create a div with your category menu with display none and have a display block when you hover.

For example:

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
}

.element:hover~.menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p class="element">Element to hover</p>
<div class="menu">
  Block to display on hover
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! I need a solution for a react.js app, that uses tailwindcss.